using useMemo to improve mounting time/memoing HTML?
I'm curious if there is a real performance gain in what I did and it's not just in my mind.
I basically had an ImageCard component which took an image and had some extra stuff that took a bit to render.
So, the code went something like this:
const [memoized, setMemoized] = useState<[id: string]: JSX.Element | undefined>({})

const [images, setImages] = useState<{image: any; id: string}[]>([])

const handleDisplayImageCard = (image: any) => {
  return <ImageCard image={image}/>
}

useEffect(() => {
  images.map(imageTuple => {
    if(memoized[imageTuple.id])
      return
   
    setMemoized( prevState => {...prevState, [imageTuple.id]: handleDisplayImageCard(imageTuple.image) }
    
  }
}, [images])

Then instead of returning the image cards I would just use their "memoized" version. Now, the reason why I tried this is because the ImageCard would be constantly mounted/remounted at different spots in the DOM and it empirically had better performance to pass the "memoized" jsx rather than pass the normal JSX component.
What exactly happens in this case? Is there any merit to using useMemo to save html?

Why not just use memo?

@EzioMercer Yeah, i guess my main concern is whether React.memo would act any different from what I did
